# Getting Textfield Values from Custom Table View Cell

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Items are loaded up on dynamic table view from server ... I need to send back a quantity number for each item which is entered through the textfield. I cannot create an outlet for the textfield because it gives me the error: outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I also tried to reference the textfield with a tag (`UITextField *countTextfield = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:4];`) but this does not grab the value I type in.

When I click Save Count I want to send back json in the form:

> {"InventoryID":"1231","manual_quantity":234}
>   {"InventoryID":"232","manual_quantity":23}
>   {"InventoryID":"214","manual_quantity":1241}
>   {"InventoryID":"241","manual_quantity":1123241}

Where manual_quantity is the value that is typed into the textfield

**please see images I have linked**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you remove the `php` tag because there is no php code and the answer seems to be in your mobile app (at a first glance)?

Comment: I'd recommend a search for `uitextfield uitableviewcell` ... you will find many articles, discussions and tutorials about just how to do this. Certainly it will give you much more information than an answer to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Something that works for me to notify table view cells changes, is to define a `protocol` for the table view cells to notify of their changes and implement the protocol in a view controller, that will be notified of those changes.

1. Define a protocol.
2. Implement the `protocol` in a view controller.
3. Define in the table view cell a member of type `protocol`.
4. In the `UITableView cellForRowAt` or any convenient method set the table view cell member of type `protocol` to `self` (i.e. the view controller implementing the `protocol`).

With this `protocol` mechanism, table view cells can notify of their changes with their actual values to any class implementing the `protocol`.

In pseudo-code using a `CellDelegate` protocol:

In the view controller:

```
// View controller
protocol CellDelegate {
    func updateQuantity(inventory: String, quantity: Int)
}

class MyUIViewController: UIViewController, CellDelegate {

    func updateQuantity(inventory: String, quantity: Int) {
        // Update quantity for given inventory
    }

}
```

In the table view cell:

```
public class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
...

@IBOutlet weak var inventory: UIText!
@IBOutlet weak var quantity: UIText!

var cellDelegate: CellDelegate?

// Table view cell
@IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    // inventory and quantity being outlets in the table view cell.
    cellDelegate.updateQuantity(inventory, quantity)
}
```

Apologise the pseudo code is a little bit Swiftish.

Answer (score 0):

First set tag to your textField in cellForRowAtindexPath.
And Set delegate to textField.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textField.tag = indexpath.row
    cell.textField.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Now get data from textField using Tag at a time user writes.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let result = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string

        let Dic:NSMutableDictionary = YourArrayName.object(at: textField.tag) as! NSMutableDictionary
        Dic.setValue(result, forKey: "InventoryID")

        YourArrayName.replaceObject(at: textField.tag, with: Dic)

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use block property in your custom cell. There you can send the data by callback from `textFieldDidEndEditing` method.

Answer (score -1):

you can store the text to any mutable array by the delegate method of UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Like below method.

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    //when you press return key it will save the text to your mutable array
    textField.endEditing(true)
    self.textFieldValueArray.add(textField.text!)
    return true
  }
```

and in your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) delegate method use

```
  cell.textField.delegate = self
```

Like below.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self

    return cell
  }
```

and finally you can use your text value like below.

```
 @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //here textFieldValueArray is a mutable array
    for each in textFieldValueArray {
        print(each)
    }
}
```

finally you can use several UITextFieldDelegate method which fulfill your purpose